# OdbcDataReader not able to see parameters when executed

Tags: c#, .net, odbc, system.data

When trying to execute a stored procedure `using System.Data.Odbc;` my application crashes because it is unable to find the parameter `"@report"`.

This is my code:

```
DataTable information = new DataTable();
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(@"usp_BS_REPORT_LINE_LIST", _conn);

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

OdbcParameter parameter = new OdbcParameter("@report",OdbcType.VarChar);
parameter.Value = "rep1";
cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);

_conn.Open();
OdbcDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dataReader.Read())
{
    information.Load(dataReader);
}

_conn.Close();
```

As you can see I have declared the parameter, how do I get around this?

Exact error message:

> ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Procedure or function 'usp_BS_REPORT_LINE_LIST' expects parameter '@report', which was not supplied.

Edit:
As requested by Steve, the procedure

```
CREATE PROC dbo.usp_BS_REPORT_LINE_LIST 
    @report varchar(128)    -- report to display
AS 

SET NOCOUNT ON

SELECT 
    s.REPORT_SECTION_NAME, l.REPORT_LINE_NAME, l.REPORT_LINE_USER_NAME
FROM
    BS_REPORT r
    INNER JOIN BS_REPORT_SECTION s ON s.BS_REPORT_ID=r.BS_REPORT_ID
    INNER JOIN BS_REPORT_LINE l ON l.BS_REPORT_SECTION_ID=s.BS_REPORT_SECTION_ID
WHERE 
    r.REPORT_NAME=@report
ORDER BY 
    s.BS_REPORT_SECTION_ID, l.REPORT_LINE_NAME

RETURN 0

GO`
```

Comment: Everything seems ok on the C# side. Could you share the SP code?

Comment: @Steve I have added the Procedure, it works when running in the management studio

Comment: Sorry,no idea. This seems all correct. The only "idea" I have is to verify the connectionstring to check if you are using the correct database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried replacing

```
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(@"usp_BS_REPORT_LINE_LIST", _conn);
```

With

```
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("{call usp_BS_REPORT_LINE_LIST(?)}", _conn);
```